# pacmd list-cards - Sound card detected by lspci but not available as an output device - Realtek ALC1220 / AMD Starship/Matisse

Tags: 20.04, sound

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 - kernel `5.8.0-53-generic`.

I have a **Realtek ALC1220 / AMD Starship/Matisse** integrated sound card that is not being made available for use but it does get detected.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
   0b:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1aeb] (rev a1)
      Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] TU116 High Definition Audio Controller [1462:3850]
      Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
      Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
   --
   0d:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
      Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1849:2225]
      Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
      Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

I don't know why it gets depicted as "**AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]**" because according to the motherboard specs, it is a **Realtek ALC1220** and the Realtek chip is on the motherboard.

Then when I do `hwinfo --sound` it also gets shown:

```
$ hwinfo --sound
38: PCI b00.1: 0403 Audio device                                
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: 94OI.jIn_AT3E4+2
  Parent ID: w+J7.mexhps_MX6B
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.1
  SysFS BusID: 0000:0b:00.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "nVidia Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1aeb 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x3850 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfc080000-0xfc083fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 124 (444 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00001AEBsv00001462sd00003850bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #7 (PCI bridge)

39: PCI d00.4: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: 6mF5.Guo4_MApwo4
  Parent ID: JZZT.YJhZDzGYdS4
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.4
  SysFS BusID: 0000:0d:00.4
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1022 "AMD"
  Device: pci 0x1487 "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1849 "ASRock Incorporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x2225 
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfcc00000-0xfcc07fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 126 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001022d00001487sv00001849sd00002225bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #32 (PCI bridge)
```

But when I do `pacmd list-cards` it does not get shown so I can't switch to it:

```
$ pacmd list-cards
   1 card(s) available.
      index: 0
      name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_0b_00.1>
      driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
      owner module: 7
      properties:
         alsa.card = "0"
         alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
         alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 124"
         alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
         device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0b:00.1"
         sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.1/sound/card0"
         device.bus = "pci"
         device.vendor.id = "10de"
         device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
         device.product.id = "1aeb"
         device.product.name = "TU116 High Definition Audio Controller"
         device.string = "0"
         device.description = "TU116 High Definition Audio Controller"
         module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
         device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
      profiles:
         output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
         output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: unknown)
         output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-stereo-extra6: Digital Stereo (HDMI 7) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround-extra6: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 7) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         output:hdmi-surround71-extra6: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 7) Output (priority 600, available: no)
         off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
      active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
      sinks:
         alsa_output.pci-0000_0b_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#0: TU116 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
      sources:
         alsa_output.pci-0000_0b_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#0: Monitor of TU116 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
      ports:
         hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
         hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
               device.product.name = "VX2363 Series"
         hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
         hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
         hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
         hdmi-output-5: HDMI / DisplayPort 6 (priority 5400, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
         hdmi-output-6: HDMI / DisplayPort 7 (priority 5300, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

`alsamixer` does allow me to select it but when I do, all I get is "This device does not have controls" and that's it.

During boot, I get: `snd_hda_intel 0000:0d:00.4: no codecs found!`

It does not get listed in Pulse Audio->Output Devices.

Running `dmesg | grep -i snd`

```
[    4.686119] snd_hda_intel 0000:0b:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.686207] snd_hda_intel 0000:0b:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    4.686215] snd_hda_intel 0000:0b:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    4.686305] snd_hda_intel 0000:0d:00.4: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.692177] snd_hda_intel 0000:0d:00.4: no codecs found!
[    5.083933] snd_hda_intel 0000:0b:00.1: bound 0000:0b:00.0 (ops nv50_audio_component_bind_ops [nouveau])
[  614.918468] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg hid_logitech_hidpp udp_diag inet_diag input_leds joydev hid_logitech_dj hid_generic bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth usbhid ecdh_generic hid ecc nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) ip6table_mangle iptable_mangle xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter xt_NFQUEUE vboxdrv(OE) xt_tcpudp bpfilter snd_hda_codec_hdmi edac_mce_amd nouveau snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg binfmt_misc kvm_amd snd_hda_codec iwlmvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep kvm mxm_wmi cdc_ether mac80211 snd_pcm usbnet video libarc4 r8152 crct10dif_pclmul ttm snd_seq_midi nls_iso8859_1 ghash_clmulni_intel mii snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_rawmidi iwlwifi cec snd_seq rc_core ucsi_ccg aesni_intel i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device fb_sys_fops snd_timer crypto_simd syscopyarea typec_ucsi cryptd sysfillrect typec glue_helper cfg80211 k10temp wmi_bmof ccp snd sysimgblt
```

Running the following command does not fix the problem:

`sudo modprobe snd_hda_codec_realtek`

Running the following commands do not fix the problem:

```
echo "0000:0b:00.1" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/snd_hda_intel/unbind
modprobe -r snd_hda_intel
modprobe snd_hda_intel probe_mask=0x103
```

Running the following commands also do not fix the problem:

```
echo "0000:0b:00.1" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/snd_hda_intel/unbind
modprobe -r snd_hda_intel
modprobe snd_hda_intel probe_mask=0x1ff
```

I have to run that `unbind` command first otherwise I won't be able to remove the module because it's in use.

Output of `ls /proc/asound`

`card0  card1  cards  devices  Generic  hwdep  modules  NVidia  oss  pcm  seq  timers  version`

Output of `ls /proc/asound/card0`

`codec#0  eld#0.0  eld#0.1  eld#0.10  eld#0.11  eld#0.12  eld#0.13  eld#0.14  eld#0.15  eld#0.2  eld#0.3  eld#0.4  eld#0.5  eld#0.6  eld#0.7  eld#0.8  eld#0.9  id  pcm10p  pcm11p  pcm12p  pcm3p  pcm7p  pcm8p  pcm9p`

Output of `ls /proc/asound/card1` (which is the one we need to get working)

Output of `ls /proc/asound/card1`

`id`

Output of `cat /proc/asound/card1/id`

`Generic`

Contents of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

I looked here: "https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1022-1487-1462-cb86" - **Device 'AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller'**

It does not look too good.

I found this discussion here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206543 and mine is also a 1022:1487 but I have an AsRock B550 Taichi motherboard, not a TRX. It shouldn't matter, vendor ID and device ID do match.

I looked in BIOS/EFI and I ensured HD Audio is enabled.

I am out of options, I don't know what else to try. Currently I am getting audio via HDMI but that will not help me if I want to use a microphone.

I tried other distrbutions too - same issue so I don't think this is related to Ubuntu specifically.

I compiled a custom kernel 5.12.4, loaded it up but nada - same issue.

I also tried `sudo alsa force-reload` but nothing, the thing just won't get shown as an output device but does get detected.

Comment: It sounds like your pc is recent, i would try newer ubuntu 21.04 (you tried newer kernel but there are  others sound components to upgrade )

Comment: Turns out I had a copy of 21.04 (Live) already so I just booted it up but issue remains unfortunately, `pacmd list-cards` does not list the card. Something I forgot to mention, `aplay -l` also does not list the card. I have taken all of the reasonable steps I know of to t/s this and because I knew this will be a problem, I already bought a Sound Blaster Audigy Rx which appears to be supported (haven't installed it yet). I don't know if I should file a bug-report to kernel.org or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Went through most of the steps attempted in the question myself to no avail.

Looking into it some people reported having success disabling then enabling HD Audio in BIOS/UEFI with a full power shutdown between.

BIOS updates also seem to resolve some people's issues.

These solutions didn't work for me but I didn't see them listed in your attempts.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1168571)